# How to flatten the text in the article (css and html)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to ask something that related about CSS and HTML.
I have a travel blog and I want to add new  like a related post on Time.com on my article post, but I have a problem.

What do I need?

A new section like a related post on Time.
Screenshot: [Time.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82TBj.png).

My problem: [The text can't flatten the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDlAQ.png).

How can I make that text/article like Time.com?
Thanks

My HTML code:

```
    <div class="resources">
      <h4>Other facts</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>United Arab Emirates Facts</li>
          <li>Venice Facts</li>
          <li>Great Wall of China Facts</li>
          <li>Dead Sea Facts</li>
          <li>Grand Canyon Facts</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.resources }
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would need is add `float` to the image, so that the text nicely wraps around your image. i think that answers your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. That's not an image but a normal text with link. See my update. Any clue?

Comment: in that case i would take a look at VXp's answer, using a list and styling that. That way you can add other items to the list, and the formatting will not change. Judging by your question i thought you meant something else.

Answer (score 0):

it's work for `<p>` like this:

```css
.resources > ul {
   width: 30%;
   float: left;
   margin-left: -30px;
}
.resources p {
   margin-top: -30px;
}
.resources h4 {
   margin-bottom: -5px;`
}
```

```html
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">30 Fun and Interesting Facts about Germany</h2>
<div class="resources">
<h4>Other facts</h4>
<ul>
  <li>United Arab Emirates Facts</li>
  <li>Venice Facts</li>
  <li>Great Wall of China Facts</li>
  <li>Dead Sea Facts</li>
  <li>Grand Canyon Facts</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Interesting Facts about Germany</strong> - Interested in spending some time in Germany during for your vacation? Well, it’s a good idea for you to know about some facts about Germany as mentioned below.</p>
<p>Those facts can be helpful for you to understand this country better and thus, you can enjoy your vacation more. So, here they are 30 interesting and fun facts about Germany.</p>

</div>
<ol>
  <li><p><strong>The Second Beer Consumer in the Europe</strong> - With the love of drinking beer, (to be honest, Germany is known as the Europe’s second beer consumer), it’s legal to drink anywhere you want. The laws regarding boozing are always loose. It’s even possible for teenagers to buy and drink alcohol freely by the age of 14! The first beer consumer in the EU is Ireland. What cool facts about Germany.</p></li>
  <li><p><strong>College Education Is Free for Everyone!</strong> - Good news for you who want to go to Germany to college and studies in Germany. It’s among the facts about Germany that college education is free even for non-Germans. The government thinks that it’s entirely unjust to ask for tuitions from the students of higher education. So, do you have more urge to get a scholarship there and studies in Germany?</p></li>
```

But, if the element contains the other `<ol>` and `<li>`, that should not work.

And how about if I used the HTML element like this?

```html
    <p><strong>Interesting Facts about Germany</strong> - Interested in spending some time in Germany during for your vacation? Well, it’s a good idea for you to know about some facts about Germany as mentioned below.</p>
<p>Those facts can be helpful for you to understand this country better and thus, you can enjoy your vacation more. So, here they are 30 interesting and fun facts about Germany.</p>
    
<div class="resources">
    <h4>Other facts</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>United Arab Emirates Facts</li>
      <li>Venice Facts</li>
      <li>Great Wall of China Facts</li>
      <li>Dead Sea Facts</li>
      <li>Grand Canyon Facts</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<ol>
  <li><p><strong>The Second Beer Consumer in the Europe</strong> - With the love of drinking beer, (to be honest, Germany is known as the Europe’s second beer consumer), it’s legal to drink anywhere you want. The laws regarding boozing are always loose. It’s even possible for teenagers to buy and drink alcohol freely by the age of 14! The first beer consumer in the EU is Ireland. What cool facts about Germany.</p></li>
  <li><p><strong>College Education Is Free for Everyone!</strong> - Good news for you who want to go to Germany to college and studies in Germany. It’s among the facts about Germany that college education is free even for non-Germans. The government thinks that it’s entirely unjust to ask for tuitions from the students of higher education. So, do you have more urge to get a scholarship there and studies in Germany?</p></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give the ul the class .resources?

```
<div class="resources">
<h4>Other facts</h4>
<ul class ="resources">
    <li>United Arab Emirates Facts</li>
    <li>Venice Facts</li>
    <li>Great Wall of China Facts</li>
    <li>Dead Sea Facts</li>
    <li>Grand Canyon Facts</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not yet, but I just tried and it has not worked yet.